How can i use server component in client component?
i wanna to use server component in client component.
when i use use client in parent component all child component convert to client component i wanna render server component in parent client component its possible or not.
i wanna render some components in server but when use server components in client component  all server components render on the client side. But i need to render from the server side :?
Has anyone ever tried something like this?
Or did he implement something like this?

You can't import server Components within Client Components - quoting to Next.js docs

The following pattern is not supported. You cannot import a Server Component into a Client Component

However, you can accept Server Components into Child Components via the children prop. Example from the docs
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

The components will render independently.
